# Romanian visa processing time for short stay visa

Tags: visas, romania, application-status

I've applied for a Romanian business visa on August 15 through the online website. However, it is still says:

> Request - Short stay visa
>      Status of your visa application - Sent for validation

As I understand, the processing time is 14 days for a short STAY visa. Now it's 14 business days and almost 3 weeks. I just wonder what should I do?
Do I need to send the original document by post?
CAN someone suggest do I need to wait for further or do I need to contact the office?

Comment: Personally, if submitting documentation with the application is not required I wouldn’t send any original documents until requested to do so.

Comment: @Traveller yes I agree, even they mentioned on the website that they will evaluate first and request originals if necessary.  But still status is sent for validation :(

Comment: This was due to the tempory closure of Sydney Romanian consulate.